# How to get the last index of a char in a string?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, indexof

I have the following task:
There is an xml element containing a long string. I need to use xsl to transform this element into a number of html `<input>` tags. It works like this: if the string is longer than an `<input>` field can hold without scrolling I call the same template recursively to create another input field with the remainig text.

The problem is that the string is often splitted right in the middle of the word which is not nice.

So I need to find the position of the last `space` character that is not bigger than the size of the substring that fits into the `<input>` tag and print only the substring before it on the line.

So I prepare a substring of max length, that can fit in the field, but I have no idea of how to get the index of the last `space` in it and pass it as a parameter into the next call of the function.

**UPD:** here is what I've got so far

```
<xsl:template name="multilineInput">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="maxFirst" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="firstLineWidth" select="."/>



    <input>
        <xsl:attribute name="readonly">readonly</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">input_multiline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">width = "<xsl:value-of select="$firstLineWidth"/>"</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 1, $maxFirst)"/></xsl:attribute>
    </input>

    <xsl:if test="$maxFirst &lt; string-length($input)">
        <xsl:call-template name="multilineInput">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring($input, $maxFirst+1, string-length($input)-$maxFirst)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxFirst" select="110"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="firstLineWidth" select="'980'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation imlements a simple and efficient algorithm: the last space in a string is the first space in the reversed string**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="lastCharIndex">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
         "'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="lastCharIndex">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="pChar" select="' '"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vRev">
    <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
     <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pText"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "string-length($pText) - string-length(substring-before($vRev, $pChar))"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="reverse">
  <xsl:param name="pStr"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLength" select="string-length($pStr)"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$vLength = 1"><xsl:value-of select="$pStr"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vHalfLength" select="floor($vLength div 2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vrevHalf1">
        <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
         <xsl:with-param name="pStr" 
              select="substring($pStr, 1, $vHalfLength)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="vrevHalf2">
        <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
         <xsl:with-param name="pStr" 
              select="substring($pStr, $vHalfLength+1)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="concat($vrevHalf2, $vrevHalf1)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
41
```

Comment: Ok, now that we've got this 41, I'm not sure I understand how to use it correctly. It prints the value, but I don't know how I should pass it as a param to another template or how I should alter my current template to make use of this. I added an example of what I have at the moment and will be grateful for an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The following recursive template can be used to return the last-index of a given delimiter:

```
<xsl:template name="last-index-of">
    <xsl:param name="txt"/>
    <xsl:param name="remainder" select="$txt"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($remainder, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="last-index-of">
                <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="$txt"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="remainder" select="substring-after($remainder, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>      
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="lastIndex" select="string-length(substring($txt, 1, string-length($txt)-string-length($remainder)))+1"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($remainder)=0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($txt)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$lastIndex>0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="($lastIndex - string-length($delimiter))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It can be invoked like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="last-index-of">
    <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="' '"></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

And returns: `41`

You can assign the result of the template call to a variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="last-index">
    <xsl:call-template name="last-index-of">
        <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="' '"></xsl:with-param>
     </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Ok, now that we've got this 41, I'm not sure I understand how to use it correctly. It prints the value, but I don't know how I should pass it as a param to another template or how I should alter my current template to make use of this. I added an example of what I have at the moment and will be grateful for an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @svz, Your current question is well-defined and has been fully answered. Please, think well how to define a new question with the problem you are now facing -- there must be a complete (but small) source XML document, the exact wanted result, and description for the rules that the transformation should implement. S for using the result of calling a template -- you have to call the template inside the body of an `xsl:variable` -- then just use that variable -- in our case its value will be 41.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Thank you. Just didn't think it was worth posting a new question.

Comment: Yes, 41 is the correct position. I was thinking of a `0` based index; the result of working with multiple languages and familiarity with Java and JavaScript. I also updated my answer to handle several edge cases that I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the EXSLT `split` template ([description](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html); [implementation](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/split/str.split.template.xsl)) or `tokenize` to split the string up by spaces. Then you could print all the text nodes except the last one, and/or use the length of the last text node to get the index of the last space.

See also [this template](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/199905/post60130.html) which you could adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will check it as soon as I can.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no EXSLT support in the provided XSL processor.

Comment: @svz: The implementation I linked to does not require any special support. It's just a standard XSLT 1.0 template.